# Is looking at an eclipse worse than looking at the sun?

Tags: visible-light, sun, vision, eclipse, laboratory-safety

I understand why looking at the sun is bad.  I also understand that looking at the eclipse is bad.  Is it more dangerous to glance at an eclipse than the sun, assuming you avert your eyes right very quickly?

I assume that the dangers of looking at an eclipse is that there is less light coming off the eclipse, but that the energy is similar meaning physically my eyes wont shut/pupils won't react the same?

Can someone help me with the science that makes eclipses so much more dangerous to look at then the sun, if this is the case?

Answer (score -1):

I think that the answer is that normally, it's super painful and way too bright to look at the sun. During a partial Eclipse, it becomes slightly more comfortable for the short term, even though it is still dangerous. So it's easier to look at it for like 5 seconds, when you can't look at it for like even 1 seconds normally

Comment: Please back this answer up with suitable references.

Comment: We just had a partial eclipse that covered 83% of the Sun. There was no visible difference for the naked eye. It was as bad to glance at the sun as usual. So it is not easier to look even for a fraction of second. If you did not know, you could not tell that there is an eclipse.  But if you know you may be tempted to look whereas usually there is no reason to look into the sun.